# How to check each value is greater or less than zero in csv file using python?

Tags: csv, python-3.4

I want to check each value of one column and according to the values give them label (trends) on the next column. For example, if the value is greater than zero or equal or less than zero, according to this positive , negative and same labels are to be written in next column.

My input file is look like this :

```
     Weightage  /// column name
     0.000555
     0.002333
     0
     -0.22222
And I want my output file is look like:

    Weightage  Labels // column name
    0.000555   positive
    0.002333   positive
    0          same
    -0.22222   negative
```

Any one can help me??

The code is:

```
print (results)
 for r in results:
   if r >0:
       print("test")
       label = "positive"
       print(label)
   elif r == 0.0:
    label = "equal"
    print(label) 
  else:
    print("nothing")
```

I have problem in 'r' for loop.
  The error occur :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\col.py", line 23, in <module>
    if r >0:
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() > int()
```

Comment: You appear to have confused this with a code-writing service. Where's **your attempt**, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: print (results)
for r in results:
    if r >0:
        print("test")
        label = "positive"
        print(label)
    elif r == 0.0:
        label = "equal"
        print(label) 
    else:
        print("nothing")
in this code , i check only the conditions and want output on shell.

Comment: **Edit the question**, after reading [ask]

Comment: i have no enough rights to edit question.

Comment: That is incorrect, you can always edit your own posts.

Comment: ...click where it says edit? Or: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31102477/edit

Comment: Did you *read* the error message? `r` is a tuple. Have you tried finding out what's in it?

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, it looks like you are confusing rows and columns. I suggest using more explicit names. It helps to avoid confusion. Also, do not compare strings to numeric types like integers. It will give surprising results in Python 2. In Python 3, it is an error.

```
for row in results:
    column = row[0]  # The first column of this row.
    value = float(column)  # The csv module returns strings, so we should
                           # turn them into floats for numeric comparison.
    if value > 0:
        print "positive"
    elif value < 0:
        print "negative"
    else:
        print "zero"
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider accepting the answer. Thanks :)